# Proving $(x_1 x_2 \cdots x_n)^{-1} = x_n^{-1} x_{n-1}^{-1} \cdots x_2^{-1}x_1^{-1}$ for $x_i $ in group $G$

Tags: group-theory, induction, solution-verification

Let $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n \in G$ for some group $G$. We wish to prove that
$$(x_1 x_2 \cdots x_n)^{-1} = x_n^{-1} x_{n-1}^{-1} \cdots x_2^{-1} x_1^{-1}.$$
I'm not sure if the correct way to proceed is by showing the multiplication out, which doesn't seem to me to be required for the inductive step. Here is what I have so far.

> *Proof.* Let $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n \in G$ for some group $G$. We proceed by induction on $n$.
> When $n = 1$, we have
> $$x_1^{-1} = x_1^{-1}.$$
> Less trivially, when $n = 2$, we have
> $$\begin{align}
> (x_1 x_2)(x_2^{-1} x_1^{-1}) &= x_1 (x_2 x_2^{-1})x_1^{-1} \\
> &= x_1 e x_1^{-1} \\
> &= (x_1 e)x_1^{-1} \\
> &= x_1 x_1^{-1} \\
> &= e,
> \end{align}$$
> and
> $$\begin{align}
> (x_2^{-1} x_1^{-1})(x_1 x_2) &= x_2^{-1} (x_1^{-1} x_1)x_2\\
> & = x_2^{-1} e x_2 \\
> &= x_2^{-1} (ex_2) \\
> &= x_2^{-1} x_2 \\
> &= e,
> \end{align}$$
> so $(x_1 x_2)^{-1} = x_2^{-1} x_1^{-1}$.
> Supposing inductively that the result holds when $n = k$,
> $$
> (x_1 x_2 \cdots x_k)^{-1} = x_k^{-1} x_{k-1}^{-1} \cdots x_2^{-1} x_1^{-1},$$
> we prove the result when $n = k + 1$:
> \begin{align*}
> (x_1 x_2 \cdots x_k x_{k+1})^{-1} & = ((x_1 x_2 \cdots x_k)x_{k+1})^{-1} = x_{k+1}^{-1} (x_1 x_2 \cdots x_k)^{-1} \\
> & = x_{k+1}^{-1} (x_k^{-1} x_{k-1}^{-1} \cdots x_2^{-1} x_1^{-1}) \\
> & = x_{k+1}^{-1} x_k^{-1} x_{k-1}^{-1} \cdots x_2^{-1} x_1^{-1}.
> \end{align*}

How does this look?

Comment: looks good to me

Comment: btw: one can prove that the left inverse in a monoid (set with associative operation with neutral element) is also the right inverse. That is, you only need to do it on one-side (https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Equality_of_left_and_right_inverses_in_monoid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is fine.

Nitpicking: your use of associativity misses a few steps; also, it suffices in a group to check whether a candidate inverse of an element is a one-sided inverse for it to be an inverse.

Comment: Could you explain where I missed some steps of associativity? I'm not able to see it; this is generally something I try to be very careful with.

Comment: For example: $$\begin{align} \color{red}{(}x_1x_2\color{red}{)}(x_2^{-1}x_1^{-1})&=x_1\color{red}{(}x_2(x_2^{-1}x_1^{-1})\color{red}{)}\\ &=x_1 ((x_2 x_2^{-1})x_1^{-1})\\ &=x_1(ex_1^{-1})\\ &=x_1x_1^{-1}\\ &=e.\end{align}$$